# How to disable backref for certain citations?

Tags: back-referencing

According to http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/backref.pdf:

> If a citation should not be back cited, then the recording can be
> turned off by option disable and enabled again afterwards, e.g.:
>
> ```
> \bookmarksetup{disable}\cite{...}\bookmarksetup{enable}
> ```

But in the following document this does not work. I don't know how to fix it. To be precise I would like this feature with backref not hyperref.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{backref}


\begin{document}
blablabla \bookmarksetup{disable}\cite{something}\bookmarksetup{enable}
\newpage
blablabla
\cite{something}
\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\bibitem{something}
something
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems to be a typo in the manual! Instead of `\bookmarksetup` it should be `\backrefsetup`. However, this does not seem to stop the back-reference from appearing, which is why this is a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: for what it's worth, using @user30471's correction finally solved my issue where the `caption` package and `\usepackage[backref]{hyperref}` produced weird `??` in my bibliography when I referenced in a table